# Getting vsFTPd to work nicely on new CentOS installation

Tags: centos, ftp

I need to setup a temporary ftp server within the intra-net at work, and got a brand new virtual CentOS installation on one of our servers. I can reach the server via ssh, install vsFTPd and configure it. Then things got a bit complicated, since I could not ftp to the server from my machine. I keep on getting `ftp: connect: No route to host` which point to some connection problem. I have then checked that the vsFTPd is running.

After some google action, I figured out that this could be a problem due to passive connections, and followed the accepted answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/421161/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-work-with-passive-mode?rq=1) here on ServerFault.

Which then brought me the issue of getting `iptables` to work instead of `firewalld`. By following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756240/how-can-i-use-iptables-on-centos-7) on StackOverflow, I tackled that problem as well. And finally [this question and its answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/147746/vsftpd-and-iptables-how-to-configure-them-in-centos-5-5) to

> "keep trak of the ftp connections and iptables will allow them when necessary."

Still, no avail.. I can't reach the server via ftp protocol. I can, however, `ftp localhost` and that works just fine. As a last resort I did `nslookup`s on both the server- and client-side. They seem to be OK. Am I missing something obvious or is there something fishy here?

PS: I am trying to find the vsftpd.log file but cant seem to find it, does it have another name for some reason? Also worth mentioning that `journalctl` does not include anything about denied connections.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth checking the SELinux settings (http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux).

A couple of years ago I tried setting up vsFTP (I can't remember the exact version I'm afraid) on CentOS 5.5 and had a lot of difficulty. I no longer have access to the relevant machine, but I found that the default SELinux policy was to block either vsFTP itself, or the file mounts it was accessing. The only place it showed up was in the SELinux logs themselves. There is nothing obvious about the messages the vsFTP logs that let me know it was SELinux that was blocking it.